# how to show whole table without custom pipe filtering when value is not inserted

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

How do I rewrite my existing code to show me, when I land on certain page, all the data retrieved from db, and when I enter some value to pipe or to filter that data, show me only what I entered?

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of beds" [(ngModel)]="num_of_beds" ng-minlength="1">
</div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Room name</th>
      <th>Number of beds</th>
      <th>TV</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

        <tr  *ngFor="let room of rooms | SearchPipe:num_of_beds ">

            <td>{{room.roomname}}</td>
            <td>{{room.beds}}</td>
            <td>
                <span *ngIf="room.tv == '1'">
                TV: Yes
                 </span>
            <span *ngIf="room.tv != '1'">
                    TV: No
            </span>
        </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Here is the pipe :)

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'SearchPipe'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform (value, [queryString]) {

        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        console.log('transform');
        return value.filter(item=>item.beds.indexOf(queryString) !== -1);


    }

}
```

So bassically how to show whole data retrieved from db when i entere in the page and to filter only when i have something submitted whrough the field

Comment: where your pipe code , can you show that

Comment: no i have filter pipe, just need way to maybe through some if else statement to baypass when i do not have anything entered in the field for filtering

Comment: i will wait one minut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do like this , check for value of args i.e. querystring if its not present return value without filtering

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'SearchPipe'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(!args)
     return value;
    return value.filter(item=>item.beds.indexOf(args) !== -1);
  }
}
```

some what similar : [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4qbrg1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: now it shows when i enter the page but doesn't do anything when i enter some data for filtering, where to define  what is queryString in pipe?

Comment: @PeraPeric - you can check stackbiz demo, one more thing you need to pass value of query string ..and pipe is dumb component and its need input , in your case num_of_bed is that input

Comment: @PeraPeric - can you paste thos adjustment so i can update my answer or you can update my answer accordinly